# Regex Preg_match for licence key 25 alphanumeric and 4 hyphens

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm still trying to get to grips with regex patterns and just after a little double-checking if someone wouldn't mind obliging!

I have a string which should either contain:

- A 10 digit (numbers and letters) licence key, for example: 1234567890 OR
- A 25 digit (numbers and letters) licence key, for example: `ABCD1EFGH2IJKL3MNOP4QRST5` OR
- A 29 digit licence number (25 numbers and letters, separated into 5 group by hyphens), for example: `ABCD1-EFGH2-IJKL3-MNOP4-QRST51`

I can match the first two fine, using ctype_alnum and strlen functions. However, for the last one I think I'll need to use regex and `preg_match`.

I had a go over at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pP6bN7/1) and came up with the following:

```
  preg_match('^([A-Za-z0-9]{5})+-+([A-Za-z0-9]{5})+-+([A-Za-z0-9]{5})+-([A-Za-z0-9]{5})+-+([A-Za-z0-9]{5})', $str);
```

Which seems to match what I'm looking for.
I want the string to only contain an exact match for a string beginning with the licence number, and contain nothing other than mixed upper/lower case letters and numbers in any order and hyphens between each group of 5 characters (so a total of 29 characters - I don't want any further matches). No white space, no other characters and nothing else before or after the 29 digit key.

Will the above work, without allowing any other combinations? Will it stop checking at 29 characters? I'm not sure if there is a simpler way to express this in regex?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You forget anchors and regex delimiters. Also, I believe the `+` are misplaced, remove them. Use `'~^[A-Za-z0-9]{5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}$~'`.  Or even `'~^[A-Za-z0-9]{5}(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}){4}$~'`. Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/jC3xV2/3).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thanks for the quick response, its greatly appreciated. Can you explain what the shortened version means? I'm trying to understand regex better. Thus meaning I don't have to keep asking on here bothering you all! Also if you submit this as an answer I'll be able to accept if it works (when my time limit on accepting answers passes!)

Comment: *if it works* is the point why I am not posting that. Does it work? The shortened version is just the same as the longer ones, it just uses a limiting quantifier `{4}` so as not to repeat the pattern 4 times. Note that `$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Sorry, no offence intended. I just hadn't tested it yet. I've tried it now and it doesn't seem to work with the shortened version. with or without the ~ at beginning and end.

Comment: What does it mean it "does not work"? [It works](https://ideone.com/Ibn9p9) here.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, my mistake it does work, both the short and long versions. I had a typo in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point is that you need to use both `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) anchors. Also, when you use `+` after `(...)`, you allow 1 or more repetitions of the whole subpattern inside the `(...)`. So, you need to remove the `+`s and add the `$` anchor. Also, you need regex delimiters for your regex to work in PHP `preg_match`. I prefer `~` so as not to escape `/`. Maybe it is not the case here, but this is a habit.

So, the regex can look like

```
'~^[A-Za-z0-9]{5}(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}){4}$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jC3xV2/3)

The `(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}){4}` matches 4 occurrences of `-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}` subpattern. The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group whose matched text does not get stored in any buffer (unlike the capturing group).

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Ibn9p9):

```
$re = '~^[A-Za-z0-9]{5}(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}){4}$~'; 
$str = "ABCD1-EFGH2-IJKL3-MNOP4-QRST5"; 
if (preg_match($re, $str, $matches)) {
    echo "Matched!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
preg_match('/^([a-z0-9]{5})(?:-(?1)){4}$/i', $str);
```

**Explanation:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
  ^             : begining of string
  (             : begin group 1
    [a-z0-9]{5} : exactly 5 alphanum.
  )             : end of group 1
  (?:           : begin NON capture group
    -           : a dash
    (?1)        : same as definition in group 1 (ie. [a-z0-9]{5})
  ){4}          : this group must be repeated 4 times
  $             : end of string
/i              : regex delimiter with case insensitive modifier
```

Comment: Hi toto, Thanks for the reply, I'm not sure the above is correct as it doesn't seem to work when i run it through my form. Wiktor's version in the comments above does however.

Comment: @BottyZ: I've forgotten the `/i` modifier, now it should work.

Comment: Yes, and still it is the same as my regex all in all. :)